# Ruby: How to use .each to iteration through an array?

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, block

In the card game bridge, four cards are given point values: Jack: 1, Queen: 2, King: 3, Ace: 4. Given an array of strings corresponding to a hand of cards (the cards are represented like so: ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]), return the total number of high card points for that hand.

I can solve this simple problem with `while` loop, but I would like to learn how to use `.each` to iterate through an array as well, Here is my code that doesn't work

```
def high_card_points(hand)
  sum = 0
  hand.each do |i|
    if hand[i] == "J"
      sum += 1
    elsif hand[i] == "Q"
      sum += 2
    elsif hand[i] == "K"
      sum += 3
    elsif hand[i] == "A"
      sum += 4
    end
  end
  sum
end
```

Now, when I run it, the error `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` comes out. How should I do it in the right way?

Comment: They are not “values,” they are called “[Milton Work Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_evaluation#High_card_points)” in the first place :)

Comment: Tip: Usually `T` is used for 10 so they're all single characters.

Comment: You also have an underscore after the `#each` method call, probably a typo but worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

The problem here, is that when you use each the variable inside the block, is the object inside the array not the index, so you can work as follow:

```
def high_card_points(hand)
  sum = 0
  hand.each do |card|
    if card == "J"
      sum += 1
    elsif card == "Q"
      sum += 2
    elsif card == "K"
      sum += 3
    elsif card == "A"
      sum += 4
    end
  end
  sum
end
```

and if you execute in pry

```
[5] pry(main)* => :high_card_points
[6] pry(main)> high_card_points(cards)
=> 10
```

You can also work whit the index like with `each_index`. But you can also take an other object-functional aproach:

You can create your class or monkeypatch the class string:

```
  class String
    def card_points
      case self
      when 'J'
        1
      when 'Q'
        2
      when 'K'
        3
      when 'A'
        4
      else
        0
      end
    end
  end
```

Then proceed like this:

```
[31] pry(main)> cards.map(&:card_points).inject(0, :+)
=> 10
```

Comment: You don't need the `map` step in the last line:  `cards.sum(&:card_points)` (MRI v2.4+) or `cards.inject(0) { |t,c| t+c.card_points }`.

Comment: Thanks for this update, please consider edit the question with this points

Answer (score 1):

The error message states, "TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)" and that the exception was raised in the line `hand[i] == "J"`. The first element passed to the block by `each` and assigned to the block variable `i` is `i = hand.first #=> "2"`. We therefore have `hand["2"] == "J"`, or in fact, `hand.[]("2")`, but the method [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) requires its argument to be an integer, and there is "no implicit conversion of String into Integer".

Let me now address a different aspect of your question.

```
arr = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]
```

You could write the following.

```
arr.reduce(0) do |tot, s|
  tot + 
  case s
  when "J" then 1
  when "Q" then 2
  when "K" then 3
  when "A" then 4
  else 0
  end
end
  #=> 10
```

I can hear you. You are saying, "I said I wanted to use `.each`!". Well, you have! Let me explain.

`arr` is an instance of the class `Array`. `Array` has [Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-include)'d the module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html), which is why we can invoke the instance method [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) on `arr`. (`Array.included_modules #=> [Enumerable, Kernel]`).

Like all other instance methods in `Enumerable`, [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) requires a receiver that is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html), but `arr` is an instance of `Array`, not `Enumerator`. Ruby gets around this as follows. When `reduce` is invoked on `arr`, she sees that `arr` is not an instance of `Enumerator` so she checks to see if `arr` has a method `each` (that is, whether `arr`'s class `Array` has an instance method `each`). It does, so she invokes `each` on `arr` to obtain

```
enum = arr.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J",
  #                  "Q", "K", "A"]:each>
```

We now have the enumerator on which `reduce` can be invoked:

```
enum.reduce(0) do |tot, s|
  tot + 
  case s
  when "J" then 1
  when "Q" then 2
  when "K" then 3
  when "A" then 4
  else 0
  end
end
  #=> 10
```

You don't see `Array#each` being invoked, but it certainly is. We can confirm that by including `Enumerable` in a class that does not have a method `each` and see what happens.

```
class C
  include Enumerable
end

c = C.new
  #=> #<C:0x0000000002a118a8>
c.reduce {}
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<C:0x0000000002a118a8>)

class C
  def each
  end
end

c.reduce {}
  #=> nil
```

This is why every class that includes `Enumerable` must have an instance method `each` that returns an enumerator and why `each` is invoked on instances of that class before an instance method from `Enumerable` is called.